# how can i get without use string to array of object during formdata append?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, foreach, form-data

I want to send array of object data by formdata append. I'm getting an array to backend server but there is coming array of object by close string'[]' like this.so i want to remove this selfclose string. So please help me, how can i solve this issue?

I'm getting this one...........

```js
varientDetails: ['{"index":0.40051008889580997,"sort":"45","sku":"5","waightorquantity":"100","Unit":"ghg","mrp":"gj","discount":"iy","price":"","stock":"","minstock":"","outofstock":""}']
```

but i want data like this:

```js
varientDetails: [{"index":0.40051008889580997,"sort":"45","sku":"5","waightorquantity":"100","Unit":"ghg","mrp":"gj","discount":"iy","price":"","stock":"","minstock":"","outofstock":""}]
```

I'm using this approach

```js
varientDetails.forEach(varient => {
  formData.append(`varientDetails[]`, JSON.stringify(varient))
})
```

Comment: try `JSON.Parse()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) cannot send literal JavaScript objects. It can send...

> `USVString` or `Blob` (including subclasses such as `File`)

Your objects must be serialised as JSON which is what you're doing. To handle that on the server, you would need to parse them. Assuming you're using something like [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) and the non-file fields are available on `req.body`...

```js
const variantDetails = req.body.varientDetails.map(json => JSON.parse(json))
```

Comment: const variantDetails = req.body.varientDetails.map(json => JSON.parse(json))

Comment: when im wring this code in backend  and try to console it then this is showing error

Comment: @Ashutoshkumar what error?

Comment: promises(node:7412) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Error
    at _construct (D:\angular project\BULUCKART\updateAdminWebbuluckart\

Comment: : Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.